# Using multiprocessing with runpy

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, runpy

I have a Python module that uses `multiprocessing`. I'm executing this module from another script with `runpy`. However, this results in (1) the module running *twice*, and (2) the `multiprocessing` jobs never finish (the script just hangs).

In my minimal working example, I have a script **runpy_test.py**:

```
import runpy
runpy.run_module('module_test')
```

and a directory **module_test** containing an empty **__init__.py** and a **__main__.py**:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

print 'start'
def f(x):
    return x*x
pool = Pool()
result = pool.map(f, [1,2,3])
print 'done'
```

When I run **runpy_test.py**, I get:

```
start
start
```

and the script hangs.

If I remove the `pool.map` call (or if I run **__main__.py** directly, including the `pool.map` call), I get:

```
start
done
```

I'm running this on Scientific Linux 7.6 in Python 2.7.5.

Comment: Your `module_test` seems to be working fine without removing `pool.map` for me.

Comment: @SreejithMenon To clarify, are you calling the module via `runpy`?

Comment: No, I am calling the module directly. I wonder if calling it via runpy is the problem area.

Comment: @SreejithMenon Sorry, I should have been clearer. Calling the module directly also works for me. It's only when I try via `runpy` that I run into this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite your `__main__.py` like so:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from .implementation import f

print 'start'
pool = Pool()
result = pool.map(f, [1,2,3])
print 'done'
```

And then write an `implementation.py` (you can call this whatever you want) in which your function is defined:

```
def f(x):
    return x*x
```

Otherwise you will have the same problem with most interfaces in multiprocessing, and independently of using runpy. As @Weeble explained, when `Pool.map` tries to load the function `f` in each sub-process it will import `<your_package>.__main__` where your function is defined, but since you have executable code at module-level in `__main__` it will be re-executed by the sub-process.

Aside from this technical reason, this is also better design in terms of separation of concerns and testing.  Now you can easily import and call (including for test purposes) the function `f` without running it in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

Try defining your function `f` in a separate module. It needs to be serialised to be passed to the pool processes, and then those processes need to recreate it, by importing the module it occurs in. However, the `__main__.py` file it occurs in isn't a module, or at least, not a well-behaved one. Attempting to import it would result in the creation of another Pool and another invocation of map, which seems like a recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 0):

Although not the "right" way to do it, one solution that ended up working for me was to use runpy's `_run_module_as_main` instead of `run_module`. This was ideal for me since I was working with someone else's code and required the fewest changes.